# Mistakenly installed a template on a wordpress website

Tags: sql, wordpress, templates, restore, overwrite

I am presently helping out with installing a wordpress website on 1and1 hosting. However i accidentally installed a new template on an existing hosting with a wordpress website in place. My dillema is how to reverse and restore the displaced website. I notice that all the data is in place for the older wordpress already in place but 1and1 is not allowing me to restore this somewhat. Any help here will be seriously appreciated.

Comment: When you change a theme you change, Menus and Widgets and theme specific display settings. If you have any old backup, you might restore site from that, otherwise you will need to activate old theme and setup widgets and settings again...

Comment: Hi Moshin, great website by the way, maybe i can get a tip or two from you on how you achieved that. I dont have the theme, the back up os anything else as the website wasnt installed or designed by me. Please any help you can render will be appreciated. Do you sell themes. really like your theme

Comment: Thank you for your kind words, no sorry I do not sell themes, it was custom built for a great client of mine. Sure please ask any specific questions you have we will try to answer.

Comment: I don't know if we are allowed to ask personal or business questions here, just want to know if i can ask how much you built the site. I am a developer myself but is sometimes overwhelmed with work and would like to outsource.. Kind regards

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your kind words, I have added my personal website in the profile, you can contact me via that , it is @WarMarks Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can restore any WordPress site by restoring database. You just need to take database from your old host and upload that to your new host.

If your 1to1 hosting doesn't allow that than you can use "All-in-One WP Migration" plugin. You need to insall this plugin on your old host and export whole database and files. Then you need to install this plugin on your new host and import the data, exported from old site to this new site...

Let me know if this helps / if you need any further help...

Comment: I am not changing hosts, i just want to restore the same website on the same hosting. SOmehow the system isnt allowing me and i can see the data, theme, plugins and everything in there

Comment: If you are using same host than you can contact your hosting provided to get database backup for yesterday and than you can restore it to get all your original settings...

Comment: THANKS, will get back to 1and1 and see what they can do, do you advice i delete the present template on their that was installed mistakenly?

Comment: No. not needed. Once you restore your database, you can delete it.

You can also do one quick solution. Just activate your original template and check whether your settings are available or not?

Comment: Thanks so much, you guys are great. I will get back to 1and1 and see what can be done